# How to maintain WPA connection on reboots when connecting from terminal?

Tags: wireless, networking, command-line

Today I installed Ubuntu server, and connected to my wireless by following this steps:

```
$ ifconfig wlan0 up

$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop

$ wpa_passphrase "ssid" "password" > wpaconfig

$ sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -cwpaconfig
```

Press ctrl+z

```
$ bg

$ sudo dhclient wlan0
```

Credits for this instructions goes to this [site](http://wilhelmsen.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/connect-to-wpa-with-terminal-ubuntu/).

I am able to connect, but on reboot I have to repeat all the steps, even though it is simple and straightforward, I would prefer if I could connect automatically.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options :

### wicd

Use `wicd-cli`

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-cli
wicd-cli
```

wicd is a command line, menu driven (ncurses) configuration tool

[image]

### Proper configuration

Normally you configure your wireless in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`and `/etc/network/interfaces`

It varies a little depending on your wireless router. There is a great post on the [Ubuntu Forums Wireless Security](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=202834) that goes through the various configurations (PSK, etc).

There is also the [Ubuntu Wiki WPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WPAHowTo) page, but as you can see it could use a little love.

If you need assistance with configuration, we need a little more information about your network.